# Unable to use for comprehension to map over List within Future

Tags: scala, future

I have this issue that I have to work around every time. I can't map over something that is contained within a Future using a for comprehension.

Example:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

val f = Future( List("A", "B", "C") )
for {
  list <- f
  e <- list
} yield (e -> 1)
```

This gives me the error:

```
 error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[(String, Int)]
 required: scala.concurrent.Future[?]
              e <- list
                ^
```

But if I do this it works fine:

```
f.map( _.map( (_ -> 1) ) )
```

Should i not be able to do this by using a for comprehension, is the reason it works in my other example that I do not flatmap? I'm using Scala 2.10.0.

Comment: Since this is getting some attention over the years I'd like to add that if you want to research a bit further then monad transformers is the correct search term. Today I would actually do things a bit different to not end up with this situation.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Well, when you have multiple generators in a single for comprehension, you are *flattening* the resulting type. That is, instead of getting a `List[List[T]]`, you get a `List[T]`:

```
scala> val list = List(1, 2, 3)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> for (a <- list) yield for (b <- list) yield (a, b)
res0: List[List[(Int, Int)]] = List(List((1,1), (1,2), (1,3)), List((2,1
), (2,2), (2,3)), List((3,1), (3,2), (3,3)))

scala> for (a <- list; b <- list) yield (a, b)
res1: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3),
(3,1), (3,2), (3,3))
```

Now, how would you flatten a `Future[List[T]]`? It can't be a `Future[T]`, because you'll be getting multiple `T`, and a `Future` (as opposed to a `List`) can only store one of them. The same problem happens with `Option`, by the way:

```
scala> for (a <- Some(3); b <- list) yield (a, b)
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[(Int, Int)]
 required: Option[?]
              for (a <- Some(3); b <- list) yield (a, b)
                                   ^
```

The easiest way around it is to simply nest multiple for comprehensions:

```
scala> for {
     |   list <- f
     | } yield for {
     |   e <- list
     | } yield (e -> 1)
res3: scala.concurrent.Future[List[(String, Int)]] = scala.concurrent.im
pl.Promise$DefaultPromise@4f498585
```

In retrospect, this limitation should have been pretty obvious. The problem is that pretty much all examples use collections, and all collections are just `GenTraversableOnce`, so they can be mixed freely. Add to that, the `CanBuildFrom` mechanism for which Scala has been much criticized makes it possible to mix in arbitrary collections and get specific types back, instead of `GenTraversableOnce`.

And, to make things even more blurry, `Option` can be converted into an `Iterable`, which makes it possible to combine options with collections as long as the option doesn't come first.

But the main source of confusion, in my opinion, is that no one ever mentions this limitation when teaching for comprehensions.

Comment: Nice answer, but I think there is some copy/paste issue with the second block of code : it's the same as the first one. ;-)

Comment: this deserves two upvotes... anyway, I wonder what people think is the clearer: the `map` version or the `for yield for` nesting?

Comment: @Mortimer There's no consensus either way, and, in fact, many will use both, picking which on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 8):

Hmm, I think I got it. I need to wrap within a future as the for comprehension adds a flatmap.

This works:

```
for {
  list <- f
  e <- Future( list )
} yield (e -> 1)
```

---

When I added above I did not see any answers yet. However to expand on this it is possible to do work within one for-comprehension. Not sure if it is worth the Future overhead though (edit: by using successful there should be no overhead).

```
for {
  list1 <- f
  list2 <- Future.successful( list1.map( _ -> 1) )
  list3 <- Future.successful( list2.filter( _._2 == 1 ) )
} yield list3
```

---

**Addendum, half a year later.**

Another way to solve this is to simply use assignment `=` instead of `<-` when you have another type than the initial map return type.

When using assignment that line does not get flat-mapped. You are now free to do an explicit map (or other transformation) that returns a different type.

This is useful if you have several transformation where one step that does not have the same return type as the other steps, but you still want to use the for-comprehension syntax because it makes you code more readable.

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

val f = Future( List("A", "B", "C") )
def longRunning( l:List[(String, Int)] ) = Future.successful( l.map(_._2) )

for {
  list <- f
  e = list.map( _ -> 1 )
  s <- longRunning( e )
} yield s
```

Comment: Assigning inside for comprehensions, definitely seems like the correct solution

Answer (score 5):

Your original version doesn't compile because `List` and `Future` are different monads. To see why this is a problem, consider what it desugars to:

```
f.flatMap(list => list.map(e => e -> 1))
```

Clearly `list.map(_ -> 1)` is a list of `(String, Int)` pairs, so the argument to our `flatMap` is a function that maps lists of strings to lists of these pairs. But we need something that maps lists of strings to a `Future` of some kind. So this doesn't compile.

The version in your answer does compile, but it doesn't do what you want. It desugars to this:

```
f.flatMap(list => Future(list).map(e => e -> 1))
```

The types line up this time, but we're not doing anything interesting—we're just pulling the value out of the `Future`, putting it back into a `Future`, and mapping over the result. So we end up with something of type `Future[(List[String], Int)]`, when we wanted a `Future[List[(String, Int)]]`.

What you're doing is a kind of double mapping operation with two (different) nested monads, and that's not something a `for`-comprehension is going to help you with. Fortunately `f.map(_.map(_ -> 1))` does exactly what you want and is clear and concise.

Comment: I know what map means, but when I see it twice in a row with two meanings, it's no longer clear and I have to pause and think a sec.  I don't mind thinking, but when I pause, there's a risk I'll head for the refrigerator.

Comment: I have to agree with som-snytt, in this particular instance I had three or four transformations. So I wanted to get away from deeply nested maps. Before writhing this question I had extracted those map steps into functions and then called them in a nested third(second(first(1))) kind of style. But that reads backwards. I like for-comps because you can read them and follow a transformation flow without a lot of noise. As you state that is not really how for-comp works in this case where the monads are different (unless you use scalaz i suppose, where functions become monads as well?).

Answer (score 1):

I find this form more readable than either the serial map or the serial yield:

```
for (vs <- future(data);
     xs = for (x <- vs) yield g(x)
) yield xs
```

at the expense of the tupling map:

```
f.map((_, xs)).map(_._2)
```

or more precisely:

```
f.map((vs: List[Int]) => (vs, for (x <- vs) yield g(x))).map(_._2)
```

Comment: The code was of course an example for this question. What I was trying to do in the first place was to do some IO in a Future, then parsing the result and wrapping it in a case class and in the end piping it to another actor. I have the separate steps as def:s and wanted to apply those in a concise manner.