# Combining Scala Futures and collections in for comprehensions

Tags: scala

I'm trying to use a for expression to iterate over a list, then do a transformation on each element using a utility that returns a Future. Long story short, it doesn't compile, and I'd like to understand why. I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349603/unable-to-use-for-comprehension-to-map-over-list-within-future), which is similar, and was a great help, but what I'm trying to do is even simpler, which is all the more confusing as to why it doesn't work. I'm trying to do something like:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val numberList = List(1, 2, 3)
def squareInTheFuture(number: Int): Future[Int] = Future { number * number}
val allTheSquares = for {
                          number <- numberList
                          square <- squareInTheFuture(number)
                        } yield { square }
```

And what I get is:

> error: type mismatch;
>    found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Int]
>    required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
>          square <- squareInTheFuture(number)
>                 ^

Can someone help me understand why this doesn't work and what the best alternative is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`flatMap` requires that the type constructors of `numberList` and `squareInTheFuture(number)` are the same (modulo whatever implicit conversions the collection library does). That isn't the case here. Instead, this is a traversal:

```
val allSquaresInTheFuture: Future[List[Int]] =
    Future.traverse(numberList)(squareInTheFuture)
```

Answer (score 9):

The [`Future` companion object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future%24) has a `traverse` method that does exactly what you want:

```
val allTheSquares: Future[List[Int]] =
  Future.traverse(numberList)(squareInTheFuture)
```

This will asynchronously start all the computations and return a future that will be completed once all of those futures are completed.

Answer (score 3):

@Lee is correct. As an addition, if you are trying to do parallel computation:

```
  val numberList = List(1, 2, 3)
  val allTheSquares = numberList.par.map(x => x * x)(breakOut)
```

If you really want `Future`:

```
val allTheSquares: Future[List[Int]] = Future.traverse(numberList)(squareInTheFuture)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your for comprehension is the same as

```
val allTheSquares = numberList.flatMap(number => squareInTheFuture(number))
```

`flatMap` requires that it's argument function returns a `GenTraversableOnce[Int]`, however yours returns a `Future[Int]`, hence the mismatch.