# Future and collections foreach doesn't run

Tags: scala, parallel-processing

I got a solution for my problem which is not working. I am using Future and collection but it finish very fast which is wrong because it is not runnung the function

```
myCollection.foreach(element => Future {
  myFunction()
})
```

what is wrong with my future implementation ?

Comment: Can you explain what you're actually trying to do? It's nearly impossible to answer this without some context. What does `myFunction` do? Does it need to return a value? That block of code above **will** execute immediately, as it's dispatching the work within `Future`s.

Comment: `Future`s are executed by other threads, current thread won't block at all.

Comment: it doesn't return any value, it just parse some sentence using a third part library ...
I used .par and it speed up 3 times but I wanted to test Future ... and it is not working @LimbSoup

Comment: What do you mean by *it's not working*? What is it *supposed* to be doing?

Comment: Use `Future.traverse(myCollection)(e => Future(f(e)))` to get a Future back which you can block on, test completion of, etc. If you don't block, your test program will exit without the futures completing. Search SO for more info.

Comment: @LimbSoup suppose to run the function!!

Comment: @som-snytt foreach doesn't block in completion of futures ?

Comment: @som-snytt `traverse` is also not working!

Comment: More answers http://stackoverflow.com/q/13097754/1296806 which was a long time ago now and http://stackoverflow.com/q/20108523/1296806

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the Future api at the Scala docs site and this will be clear as crystal to you:
http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html