# How do I convert this ugly one liner into a clean scala for comprehension?

Tags: scala, list, dictionary, for-comprehension, flatmap

Hey guys I got this ugly thing:

```
val test = Some(Map("TesT",123))
val keys = test.getOrElse(Map()).keys.map(_.toLowerCase).asInstanceOf[Set[String]]
require(keys.contains("test")
```

Can I turn it (line #2) into a clean/readable for comprehension?

Here's my attempt:

```
scala> val keys = for {
     |       map <- test
     |       keys <- map.keys
     |       k <- keys
     | } yield k.toLowerCase
<console>:18: error: value toLowerCase is not a member of Char
       } yield k.toLowerCase
                 ^
<console>:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Iterable[Char]
 required: Option[?]
             keys <- map.keys
                  ^
```

Comment: Where is the "ugly" one liner ? Also... for that purpose `test.getOrElse(Map()).contains("test")` is a way better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comprehensions is just a syntactic sugar for `map`/`flatMap`. The `flatMap` method of `Option` returns another `Option`. To get a multiple values you should start with sequence, so the first line should be `map <- test.toSeq`. This explains the second error message.

The second line in the comprehension try to access `keys` using `flatMap`. It could be fixed in two ways. Either replaces it by `val keys = map.keys`, so neither `map` or `flatMap` is involved, or remove this line completely in make a call on the third one: `k <- map.keys`. This will fix fix the first error.

So you may choose between two solutions:

```
val keys = for {
       map <- test.toSeq
       val keys = map.keys
       k <- keys
 } yield k.toLowerCase
```

or

```
 val keys = for {
       map <- test.toSeq
       k <- map.keys
 } yield k.toLowerCase
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a for comprehension for this.
Clearly sequencing operations, and spelling the steps out explicitly is often more clear and readable. Just don't try to cram things into a single line:

```
 test
   .iterator
   .flatMap(_.keys)
   .map(_.toLowerCase)
   .contains("test")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original:

```
val keys = for {
             map <- test
             keys <- map.keys
             k <- keys
       } yield k.toLowerCase
```

One constraint of the *for comprehension* over `flatmap` and `map` is that it requires the [same kind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349603/unable-to-use-for-comprehension-to-map-over-list-within-future) of [*enumerator*](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/sequence-comprehensions.html) (really a monad) throughout, the first establishing which kind.  In your example, the first *enumerator* is an `Option`, so it expects `map.keys` and `keys` to be of type `Option` as well.

Another problem with your example, is that `keys` is really a single `key` taken from the set `map.keys`... so `k` would then refer to a character in the *enumurator* across `keys: String`.

Resolve the *for-comprehension* type problem by converting the initial type of the `for` comprehension to a `Seq`, allowing the following terms to be of that type (they are), and then stop after extracting the `key`:

```
val keys = for {
        map <- test.toSeq
        key <- map.keys
    } yield key.toLowerCase
```