# Scala: composing queries inside for comprehension giving errors

Tags: scala

I am trying to get this query right but getting errors. First, searchUser returns a sequence of matching UserEntries that contains unique id for user and for each of the userId, there is a second query obtains some other user info + address from another table.

Code:

```
def searchUsers(pattern: String) = auth.SecuredAction.async {
  implicit request =>
    usersService.searchUser(pattern) flatMap { usrList =>
      for {
        u <- usrList
        ui <- usersService.getUsersWithAddress(u.id)
      } yield {
        Ok(views.html.UserList(ui))
      }
    }
}
```

Signatures for the APIs used:

```
def searchUser(pattern: String): Future[Seq[UserEntry]] = ...    
def getUsersWithAddress(userId: Long): Future[Seq[(UserProfile, Seq[String])]] = ...
```

Error:

```
[error] modules/www/app/controllers/Dashboard.scala:68: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]
[error]  required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
[error]           ui <- usersService.getUsersWithAddress(u.id)
[error]              ^
[error] one error found
[error] (www/compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

If I comment out line "u <- usrList" and hardcode a userid for the next line like "ui <- usersService.getUsersWithAddress(1L)" it works. Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use multiple generators in a for comprehension, the monads have to be of the same type.  E.g. you can't:

```
scala> for{ x <- Some("hi"); y <- List(1,2,3) } yield (x,y)
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
found   : List[(String, Int)]
required: Option[?]
          for{ x <- Some("hi"); y <- List(1,2,3) } yield (x,y)
                                  ^
```

What you can do is convert one or the other to match the correct type.  For the above example, that would be:

```
scala> for{ x <- Some("hi").toSeq; y <- List(1,2,3) } yield (x,y)
res2: Seq[(String, Int)] = List((hi,1), (hi,2), (hi,3))
```

In your particular case, one of your generators is a GenTraversableOnce, and the other is a Future.  You can probably use Future.successful(theList) to get two futures.  See the answer here for example:

[Unable to use for comprehension to map over List within Future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349603/unable-to-use-for-comprehension-to-map-over-list-within-future)

Comment: If I wrap u <- usrList with Future.successful() I end up with "value id is not a member of Seq[models.UserEntry]". I was hoping "u" to be an item rather an sequence. 2nd generator needs a reference to single item - so how do I get that (I can think of traditional for loop in non-functional languages but not here..)

Comment: followed a chain of answers based on yours and finally got a solution.. since I can't seem to put a formatted piece of code in the comment, I will add it as my answer -- but accepting yours to give you due credit!

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Brian's answer arrived at a solution.. following worked (could not enter formatter block of code as comment - so adding as answer):

```
  usersService.searchUser(pattern) flatMap { usrList =>
    val q = for {
      u <- usrList
    } yield (usersService.getUserWithAddress(u.id))
    val r = Future.sequence(q)
    r map { ps =>
      Ok(views.html.UserList(ps))
    } 
  }
```

For comprehension accumulated the Futures and then the sequence was flattened and then mapped. Hope this is how it is done!

Note: also I had to change the signature of getUserWithAddress to X instead of Seq[X]